# How to remove space in Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I want to remove this space between Toolbar and TextView as in this picture:

[image]

I try to user `contentInsetStart` and `contentInsetEnd` but also not work. 
This is my full code to handle it

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctl_news"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_news_mainImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/stripes"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tb_news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:gravity="top|end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge_size" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to solve it

Comment: use gravity.! or align parent center true

Comment: In the TextView try `android:gravity="left" `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

USe the app namespace and do like this:

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Also, you might want to add:

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Remove contentInsetEnd attribute. I tried and this works

So it looks like this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try `app:titleMarginStart="0dp"`?

You should use `app` prefix for `contentInsetStart` and `contentInsetEnd` and remove the android to avoid boilerplate code

Comment: i try it also but not work also remove `android` prefix and same result

Comment: Do you try `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation` yet?

Comment: app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation works for me.